# Trigonometry - Finding value of expression

Tags: trigonometry

Question: Given $\sin x + \sin^2 x = 1$ then find the value of $$\cos^{12} x + 3\cos^{10} x + 3\cos^8 x + 6\cos^6 x + 2\cos^4 x + \cos^2 x -2$$

I have no idea where to start on this question. Please help me!

Comment: Hint: Use $\cos^2 x = 1-\sin^2 x = \sin x$ to start. So $$\cos^{12} x = (\cos^2 x)^6 = \sin^6 x$$

Comment: Well I did think of that, but I thought there must be a shorter way to do it. Let me try.

Comment: Distant cousin : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410227/solving-trigonometric-identity-with-condition

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Extremely distant cousin I would say. Some of the same elements, but it would be difficult to obtain a hint from that.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sin x=1-\sin^2x=\cos^2x$$

Squaring we get $$\sin^2x=(\cos^2x)^2\iff 1-c^2=c^4\iff c^4+c^2-1=0$$ where $c=\cos x$

Now  establish that $c^4+c^2-1$ is a factor of $$c^{12}   + 3c^{10}   + 3c^8  + 6c^6   + 2c^4   + c^2   -2$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x+\sin ^2x=1$, let's give $\sin x$ another name, $\alpha$.

$\alpha+\alpha ^2 =1$.

$\alpha^2 + \alpha -1=0$.

That gives us either

$\alpha_1=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ or $\alpha_2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Notice that $\sin(x) = \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ can't be true. So the only valid solution is $\alpha_1$.

Given that $\sin^2x=(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^2$, this means that $\cos^2x=1-(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^2$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Well I expanded the equation using $\cos^2 x = 1 - sin^2 x$

Comment: This is working out to be too long. There has to be an easier way to do it. It was a multiple choice question after all.